# QLineEdit in QCompleter doesn't show all items

Tags: qt, menu

I am trying to create a menu app (like windows search) with QCompleter.
I would like to show all items from completer when the QLineEdit is empty.
And it works first time, but when I start typing something into the `lineEdit` and I delete all characters from `lineEdit`, and then press `Enter` I see nothing. Where is my mistake?

My code is below.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{

    this->wordList << "alpha" << "omega" << "omicron" << "zeta" << "icon";

    this->lineEdit = new QLineEdit(this);

    completer = new QCompleter(wordList, this);
    completer->setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
    lineEdit->setCompleter(completer);
    completer->QCompleter::complete();

    ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

---

```
void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{

    if((event->key() == Qt::Key_Return || event->key() == Qt::Key_Enter))
    {
        if(lineEdit->text()=="")
        {
            completer->complete();
        }

        if(wordList.contains(lineEdit->text(),Qt::CaseInsensitive))
            qDebug() <<"CATCH IT";
    }
}
```

Could you please advise me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reset the completion prefix on the completer.

```
  if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Return || event->key() == Qt::Key_Enter)
  {
    if(lineEdit->text().isEmpty())
    {
      lineEdit->completer()->setCompletionPrefix("");
      lineEdit->completer()->complete();
    }
  }
```

Also if the intent is to only have it populate when return is pressed in the line edit, you will want to create your own line edit to handle that versus using the main window.

Comment: It works, Thank you! You are a king. :) Qt is really new to me, so i am on low level, thank you again!:)